# How PostSharp Handle the sessionstate?

Tags: asp.net, postsharp

I am facing the issue while when i am trying to configure the postSharp(3.1.46). Before configuration application working fine.
I found few observation.

1. Application build on vb.Net 4.0 framework.It is normal web application with visual studio 2010.
2. Every Page EnableSessionstate =false.
3. Web service session is enable in "inproc" mode and EnableSessionstate=true.
4. We configure the POSTSHARP  using postsharp.dl only not any postsharp dll like Pattern/modell.
5. We are using postsharp for capture the log.We are using  only this class OnMethodBoundaryAspect.
6. I found example mention in Postsharp site where example session as  "http://samples.postsharp.net/#PostSharp.Samples.SessionState.
7. I found they are using LocationInterceptionAspect for sessionstate.
8. I tried  all enable and disable  session.But error still same as mention below.Please do need fulhelp.

Should i need to enhance our source code to handle LocationInterceptionAspect for session state ?
Error :

"Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration."

Comment: Based on the message, the error comes not from the usage of PostSharp but from the ASP.NET configuration. Did you check whether SessionStateModule is registered as described in the error message? If you are not using SessionStateAttribute from PostSharp, then you're probably using HttpContext.Current.Session somewhere in your app directly. Try looking for the usages in your code.

Comment: Hi Alex, Our client application is using HttpContext.Current.Session only.But they are maintaining the session in database server.Not is application server.Can you please let me know.is any change required for the web.config.? Please let me know.So i am thankful to you.

Comment: They are using InProc mode.